# Aggregate totals from a result in mySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

In codeiginter - is it possible to aggregate totals from a result in mySQL using Active record?

**My table:**

```
+-----------------+---------------+----------+
|  transaction_ID |  category_ID  |  amount  |
+-----------------+---------------+----------+
|        1        |      2        |   5.0    |
+-----------------+---------------+----------+
|        2        |      1        |   6.0    |
+-----------------+---------------+----------+
|        3        |      2        |   4.1    |
+-----------------+---------------+----------+
|        4        |      3        |   1.2    |
+-----------------+---------------+----------+
|        5        |      1        |   7.0    |
+-----------------+---------------+----------+
```

**What I'd like to achieve:**

```
+---------------+----------------+
|  category_ID  |  total_amount  |
+---------------+----------------+
|       1       |      13.0      |
+---------------+----------------+
|       2       |      9.1       |
+---------------+----------------+
|       3       |      1.2       |
+---------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT category_ID, SUM(amount) totalAmount
FROM tableName
GROUP BY categoryID
```